# What is the capacity of my Maytag Washer model number LAT9604AAE?

Tags: appliances

I have a Maytag washer model number LAT9604AAE that has stopped working.  I need to have a similar size or larger washer.  What is the capacity?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the very specific information is readily available via search engines.

Answer (score 1):

A google search shows the capacity to be 2.5, according to this link.  https://www.partselect.com/Models/LAT9604AAE/

Found in the answer section near the bottom.

Comment: 2.5 pounds? kilogrammes? gallons? cu feet?

Comment: Firkins per Fortnight. ;^)

Comment: Link did not say, but cu feet would be the usual for a washer.

Comment: The [service manual](https://www.manualslib.com/manual/874524/Maytag-Lat2300.html?page=9#manual) says 2.5 Cu. Ft.

Comment: @crip659 I asked because my washing machine manual gives all the load detail in kg...

Comment: @SolarMike  Just did a fast check with amazon Canada and it seems to be 70 to 80% cu ft and the rest in lbs.  Thought maybe a few would be kgs since we are suppose to be metric.

Comment: @crip659 It's a metric washer...for metric clothes.

Comment: I used to own a car with metric wheels. I kid you not, nor did I before that know that the world over car wheels are in inches. They did it so you were forced to put specific tyres on it, 170mph-rated, run-flat. I eventually had to change the wheels when they stopped making the tyres. Imagine if that happened to your washing machine… "Can't wash these trousers mate, they're metric!"